# adding footer value to datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, footer

I am having 2 datatables. One is having the actual value of that table selected by the user and the next is having the aggregate value for that table i.e any grand total or avg. I want to display this as the footer in C# datagridview. How can I do that??? In asp.net we have RowDataBound event like that similar something is there in C# also but what it is i'm not able to find.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView column footer c#.net winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056678/datagridview-column-footer-c-net-winforms)

Comment: this was asked in april,2010 but the one which you have pointed was asked later during october,2012.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ondatabound` event of `GridView` for populating footer. Sample:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = sender as GridView;

    grid.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = CustomDataSource.GetAggregated.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    grid.FooterRow.Cells[1].Text = CustomDataSource.GetAggregated.Rows[0]["Total"].ToString();
}
```