# Fix the last row of a DataGridView even if someone clicked the column header to sort the list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, datagridview

```
Table1     Fig.
Name     | Marks
Pritam   | 80
Aruna    | 85
Uttaran  | 90
Total    | 255

DataTable dtStudentInfo = table1;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtStudentInfo;
```

After Clicking on the column header name datagridview sort in ascending order of students' name. But I want the Total row always stays at the last of list.

I want to know if there is any way by which I can remove the last row from the list which will be sorted. If this is not possible then suggest any way by which i can get the result. NOTE: I don't want any external button to sort the list.

I've solved the problem by the following way:

```
DataGridViewRow dgRowTotalCount;
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            dgRowTotalCount = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[((DataGridView)sender).Rows.Count - 1].Clone();
            for (Int32 index = 0; index < ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[((DataGridView)sender).Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Count; index++)
            {
                dgRowTotalCount.Cells[index].Value = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[((DataGridView)sender).Rows.Count - 1].Cells[index].Value;
            }
            ((DataGridView)sender).Rows.RemoveAt(((DataGridView)sender).Rows.Count - 1);
        }
    }
private void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtDGVCopy = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            dtDGVCopy.Columns.Add(col.Name);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dRow = dtDGVCopy.NewRow();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
            }
            dtDGVCopy.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }
        dtDGVCopy.Rows.Add();
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < dgRowTotalCount.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            dtDGVCopy.Rows[dtDGVCopy.Rows.Count-1][i] = dgRowTotalCount.Cells[i].Value;
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtDGVCopy;
    }
```

But its not smooth as it was before. If there is any way by which i can make it's performance as it was before that would be great.

Comment: You could use the .Frozen = true on that specific row

Comment: It won't work. I've tried.

Comment: sorry i couldn't help!

Comment: You will get an extra row in the datagridview if the edit = true option is turned on.  This is to allow somebody to add new data.  Turning the edit option to off will remove the last empty row.

Comment: Definitely, you should look for "DataGridView with footer". [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056678/5045688).

Comment: If using a DataTable, [I've derived a DataGridView class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399630/3773066) to handle just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is a solution I've come up with. Use the SortCompare event on the grid to override the sorting for a specific row:

```
    private void dgvData_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvData.Rows[e.RowIndex1].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Total" ||
            dgvData.Rows[e.RowIndex2].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Total")
        {
            if (dgvData.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                e.SortResult = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                e.SortResult = 1;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Now any row that has "Total" in the first column will always sort to the end of the grid.

(If you allow columns to be reordered then you'll need to figure out how to check the correct column)